# How to convert a PsiElement to a PsiClass

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

```
PsiElement referenceAt = psiFile.findElementAt(editor.getCaretModel().getOffset());


PsiClass parentOfType = PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(referenceAt, PsiClass.class);

WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(project, () -> {
if (referenceAt instanceof PsiClass){
    editor.getDocument().insertString(editor.getCaretModel().getOffset(), "isClass");
} else if (referenceAt instanceof PsiVariable){
    editor.getDocument().insertString(editor.getCaretModel().getOffset(), "isVariable");
}


}
```

Right now I can extract the name of the Element that the caret is standing at. My goal is to find out whether or not the PsiElement is Class.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If the caret is on a reference, and not on the actual declaration, you need to resolve that reference to get the `PsiClass`.

```java
PsiReference reference = referenceAt.getReference();
if (reference != null) {
    PsiElement target = reference.resolve();
    if (target instanceof PsiClass) {
        // do your things here
    }
}
```